# Filtering and transformation messages with MongoDB Kafka Sink Connector?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm very new to both Kafka and MongoDB but I have an existing Kafka topic which I want to consume into a Mongo database. I'm trying to avoid building my own Consumer or Connector and instead use only a [Sink Connector](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/sink-connector/). This way, I can avoid the additional maintenance, cost and complications which would come with having a separate Connector/Consumer component, as well as avoiding the work to build it in the first place. The complicated part is that I want to process the messages in two ways before doing any inserting:

1. Ignore messages whose values don't meet a condition (colour = green, for example)
2. Of those who do meet this condition, only insert certain fields from the message into the collection

The transformation part I think I can do using [Post Processors](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/sink-connector/fundamentals/post-processors/#allow-list-and-block-list-examples). However, I haven't seen an example of a way to conditionally ignore certain messages entirely. I would have thought this would be something fairly trivial for the Sink Connector to do compared to transforming data. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

1. Use [redhat debezium filter smt](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_integration/2022.q4/html/debezium_user_guide/applying-transformations-to-modify-messages-exchanged-with-kafka#setting-up-the-debezium-filter-smt) to accept only messages satisfying a condition.

   ```
   transforms=filter
   transforms.filter.type=io.debezium.transforms.Filter
   transforms.filter.language=jsr223.groovy
   transforms.filter.condition=value.colour == 'green'
   ```
2. Configure [sink-connector postprocessor](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/sink-connector/fundamentals/post-processors/#allow-list-projector-example) in order to load into collection only required fields.

   ```
   post.processor.chain=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.AllowListValueProjector
   value.projection.type=AllowList
   value.projection.list=colour,size,etc.
   ```

This is an example how you can utilize third party debezium filter smt to filter out messages and native MongoDB Kafka sink connector post processors to transform output document.